# How to parse KML file in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I want to know a simple and easy way to parse KML file and store its data in an object so that I can access its data instantly here is [my kml file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12gyD5YY45X0aKewVhB8wawlQrojwTmzs/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`KmlContainer`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/kml/KmlContainer.html) from [Google Maps KML Importing Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/kml) to access any property in a container:

```
...
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(getMap(), kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());

Iterable containers = layer.getContainers();
for (KmlContainer container : containers ) {
    if (container.hasProperty("property_name")) {
        // process property
        Log.d(TAG, "" + container.getProperty("property_name"));
    }
}
...
```

For exactly yours `kml` file for standard geometry you can use something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(17.425868, 78.459761), 16));

    // change next line for your kml source
    InputStream kmlInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.data);
    try {
        KmlLayer kmlLayer = new KmlLayer(mGoogleMap, kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());
        kmlLayer.addLayerToMap();

        ArrayList<LatLng> pathPoints = new ArrayList();

        if (kmlLayer != null && kmlLayer.getContainers() != null) {
            for (KmlContainer container : kmlLayer.getContainers()) {
                if (container.hasPlacemarks()) {
                    for (KmlPlacemark placemark : container.getPlacemarks()) {
                        Geometry geometry = placemark.getGeometry();
                        if (geometry.getGeometryType().equals("Point")) {
                            KmlPoint point = (KmlPoint) placemark.getGeometry();
                            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(point.getGeometryObject().latitude, point.getGeometryObject().longitude);
                            pathPoints.add(latLng);
                        } else if (geometry.getGeometryType().equals("LineString")) {
                            KmlLineString kmlLineString = (KmlLineString) geometry;
                            ArrayList<LatLng> coords = kmlLineString.getGeometryObject();
                            for (LatLng latLng : coords) {
                                pathPoints.add(latLng);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } 
            }

            for (LatLng latLng : pathPoints) {
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            }
        } 

    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and get something like that:

[image: KML path]

but for `<ExtendedData>` you should use external library with KML parsing support like [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) or parse your KML file as XML.

Comment: I am creating input stream like this 
val inputStream : InputStream = FileInputStream(File(path))
    val layer = KmlLayer(mMap, inputStream, applicationContext)
    val containers = layer.containers
but I am getting null in containers

Comment: I am using kotlin language

Comment: thanks, it's working before that I forgot to add the layer to map thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, @Andrii Omelchenko how I can read the ExtendedData of Kml file? I debug the app and it's not showing the value of the description tag under the Placemark.property

Comment: How can we remove these markers ? I tried removing this but not working                                 for (LatLng latLng : pathPoints)  {
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
            }

Comment: @Anish Just don't add them: remove `mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));` line.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Hi. I have kml file like this. and i want to parse that kml file and get the values from the placemark tag. when i have tried it getting null values. how to do that?

Comment: <kml>
<Document>
<description>
Area: Left: 1250485.288695; Right: 1251179.862985; Bottom: -462590.311632; Top: -461865.390194
</description>
<Region>
<LatLonAltBox>
<north>43.5539759771</north>
<west>-79.75206812</west>
<east>-79.7459992589</east>
<south>43.5463420129</south>
</LatLonAltBox>
</Region>
<name>spatialNET View Around Node Boundary: 246388</name>
<Folder>
</Folder>

Comment: @vijju Dear vijju, please create new question with your code and full text of .kml file. It's hard to help you without that.